# Laravel composer update error - Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I have a problem to update dependencies in my project. Issue:

Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some cases **It's only because of poor or interrupted internet connections**

*One solution might be changing  your internet form Wi-Fi to Ethernet.*

---

If you are using ESET antivirus, go in "Advanced Settings" and disable "HTTP-scanner" under "web access protection"

---

If you're using  Virtualbox, Then you might need to downgrade to resolve the issue

---

If you are using IPv6, try disabling it.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ESET antivirus, go in "Advanced Settings" and disable "HTTP-scanner" under "web access protection"

If you are using IPv6, try disabling it. If that solves your issues, get in touch with your ISP or server host, the problem is not at the Packagist level but in the routing rules between you and Packagist (i.e. the internet at large). The best way to get these fixed is raise awareness to the network engineers that have the power to fix it.

To disable IPv6 on Linux, try using this command which appends a rule preferring IPv4 over IPv6 to your config:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"
```

Comment: Disabling IPv6 solved the issue for me on Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too, it ended up being a Virtualbox issue. I needed to downgrade to version 5.1.6 to resolve it. (I was running 5.1.8)

Also, I read that running 5.0.28 also caused this issue, and downgrading to 5.0.10 resolved it.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer in the past 3 days. This was the solution! Upgraded to latest Virtualbox version (5.0.30) on OSX and it started working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in composer.json and then run composer update.

```
 "repositories": [
            {
                "type": "composer",
                "url": "https://packagist.org"
            },
            { "packagist": false }
        ]
```

Happy coding!